# Can legendary mats drop on Normal difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

Am I able to farm for legendary crafting materials on Normal difficulty, or must I be on Torment (1-6) for these to drop? Here is a list of the materials I mean:      http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83094-guide-legendary-crafting-materials-drop-locations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they can, but the chance is not good.

In the [2.0.4 patch](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/2-0-4), this information was posted:

> The drop rate of unique Legendary crafting materials has been significantly increased.
>   This matches the drop rate of Death's Breaths.

The drop rate for death breath as posted by a blue on the forums are as follows ([source](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83367-death-s-breath-drop-rates)):

> Quoted from Lylirra
>
> "Just as an FYI, the scaling drop rates for Death's Breath are the
>   same as Demonic Essence (i.e. they scale the same way as you progress
>   in difficulty). Currently, those drop rates are:
>
> Normal - 15%
>   Hard - 18%
>   Expert - 21%
>   Master - 25%
>   Torment 1 - 31%
>   Torment 2 - 37%
>   Torment 3 - 44%
>   Torment 4 - 53%
>   Torment 5 - 64%
>   Torment 6 - 77%

Comment: From my experience, it really doesn't match the drop rate of Death's Breaths, but I like this answer.

Comment: @Bunyip you have to keep in mind your sample size for leg mats is a lot smaller than death breaths

Comment: That's what it is, you're right, good point.

Comment: I'd say chances are pretty good for Normal, until your character is more or less comfortable in Torment. Comparing T1 to Normal, the chance is roughly doubled, for eight times the monster health.

Comment: @Bunyip You get lots more Death's Breaths but that's because it can drop from much more mobs. Legendary crafting mats can only drop from specific special mobs or events. So the percentage is looked at much less often.